# stranger as in stranger danger

Tags: semantics

A stranger is someone you don't know. By this definition, a taxi driver is a stranger. But is a taxi driver considered a stranger in the context of stranger danger?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is sought within the context of *stranger danger* (or personal safety) as the domain of discussion, rather than the English language or its usage.

Comment: (@Lawrence And this makes *stranger danger* somehow not a set phrase?) A stranger is someone you don't know personally, and *stranger danger* is that category of peril from someone you don't know. As opposed to the more likely occurrence, harm from someone with whom you're acquainted. By the way, my grandfather was a taxi driver, so certainly no stranger (or danger) to me. The key thing is acquaintance, not occupation.

Comment: @deadrat Actually, I read "stranger danger" *as* a very well-defined set phrase that provides the domain of discussion. That is, the OP isn't asking whether a taxi driver is a stranger in the context of *linguistics* or *etymology*, etc. To paraphrase the OP: "I'd like to talk about stranger danger. Is a taxi-driver a stranger?" I voted to close because I didn't think that question was on-topic at EL&U. If my interpretation is incorrect, I'd be happy to retract my vote once the question is appropriately edited for clarity.

Comment: @Lawrence *Actually, I read "stranger danger" as a very well-defined set phrase* Then it's on topic by definition as a matter of usage. The question seems to me to have an obvious answer, but that's a different consideration. In any case, your name has been reported with favor in dispatches to the CPVPV.

Comment: This is clearly a question about phrase-usage, not personal safety. I think the example given of a taxi driver is just that, an example. You could make the the question broader by asking whether it is appropriate to use this expression when referring to people who professionally deal with the public (ie service industry, or healthcare) "Whenever Bob left his daughter at the hospital he would make her repeat the mantra _stranger danger, stranger danger_"

Comment: @deadrat *Ouch*.

Comment: @Lawrence Ouch? I thought you'd have been pleased.

Comment: @deadrat *Pleased* about a veiled insult? Hardly. The OP appears to understand the word *stranger* and the term *stranger danger*. I've offered my interpretation of the OP's question. The *language* part seems to just be *"Yes, unfamiliar service providers are still technically strangers in the sense of 'stranger danger'"*, though the broader discussion (beyond *language* considerations) would include *"... but in modern society, interacting with unfamiliar service providers is all but inevitable"*, together with discussions about degrees of danger and mitigation strategies etc. ...

Comment: @deadrat ... I  think the OP is really after the *broader* discussion, not the *language* part, hence my vote to close the question as off-topic. If you see more to it as a *language* question than the *language* part I just mentioned, I invite you to make your case on Meta (ping me here, please). You have a knack of seeing things I've missed, and I would look forward to discussing the substance thereof. On the other hand, if you're only pursuing this to the point of *arg. ad hom.* because of the technicality that there is a trivial *language* answer, kindly review your own CPVPV status.

Comment: @Lawrence Unfamiliar service providers aren't "technically" strangers; they're strangers by definition as members of a subset of all unfamiliar persons. This fact makes the question trivial and might be grounds for asking the OP whether he agrees. I don't see it as an invitation to speculate on what the OP's understands, what the OP is "really" after, or whether the OP has requested that we supply mitigation strategies. My knack for interpreting questions about language as questions about language is the worst superpower ever, and even by the standards of ELU would be a waste of time on meta.

Comment: @Lawrence My comment isn't an argumentum ad hominem: I'm not saying that your reasoning is wrong because you're a member of the CPVPV; I'm saying that you're a member of the CPVPV because your reasoning is wrong. My observations may be tiresome (as one mod pointed out recently), but they certainly disqualify me as a member of the CPVPV.

Comment: @deadrat Aside from your suggestion to ask the OP, you've missed the mark with your last two-part comment.

Comment: @Apollyon Can you please elaborate on your question? In particular, there has been some debate about whether you're asking a question about English, or whether you're asking a question (which could be in any language) about stranger danger.

Comment: @Lawrence Oh, of course. *I'm* the one who's missed the mark. That must be it. Well, I guess we're done here, eh?

Comment: @deadrat Yes, as far as this question goes, we're done here. Thank you for the note about interacting with the OP.

Comment: @Lawrence Yeah, interaction. That's the ticket. I suspect that Apollyon is gone. I know I would be, but that's just me, and it's only been two days.

Comment: @deadrat I often interact with OPs in the way you suggest. If it helps, their rep count (and their 3-year tenure) suggests an established user. Regardless, it would have been nice for you or me - or anyone - to have interacted with the OP earlier. Having said that, is there any reason you're so invested in my handling of this question?

Comment: Uh… the taxi driver enters the story as a stranger but to the limited extent of presenting himself as a service provider, is exempt from any real suspicion. Is that right both in terms of language and of personal safety?

Then so long as every things the taxi driver does or says is precisely consistent with the generally expected role of a taxi driver, there should be no need to worry.

When any action or word crosses the line it's time to consider 'stranger danger' - which is tough on potential victims already sitting in what suddenly became the hot seat at the back of the cab…

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "Stranger Danger" is generally used to warn children about random people they meet. Anyone you do not know is considered a stranger.

You could consider a taxi driver a stranger in that context.

Answer (score 1):

The term suggests any stranger is a potential danger, so yes, this expression is warning that an unknown taxi driver is [a potential danger](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/1647269/woman-punched-in-the-face-by-cab-driver-because-she-needed-to-stop-on-way-back-to-get-cash/).